# admin-ajax.php access and authentication

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, learnpress

I am super new to wordpress/learnpress.

Have created a new function.

`add_action( 'wp_ajax_updateCourseTimer', 'updateCourseTimer',10,4); add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_updateCourseTimer', 'updateCourseTimer',10,4); function updateCourseTimer() { }`

The call to the endpoint https://example.com/site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php with action = updateCourseTimer works fine.

Now I need to call the same function from a mobile app. From the mobile app the call leveraging action "wp_ajax_nopriv_updateCourseTimer" works but call leveraging "wp_ajax_updateCourseTimer" doesn't work. It is basically an authentication issue.

I tired making calls with logged in user from the app but still no luck.

Question: How can one authenticate the call from an external system (mobile app), so that calls do not require *nopriv* routes. Do I need to somehow manually pass cookies from the ajax call in the app?

Again I am super new to all this and would appreciate guidance.

Thanks

With experimentation have figured out that its authentication issue. read about nonce etc. but not clear how to go about doing this.

Comment: As a developer you can build your own login system, circumventing the whole wordpress login system. This leave you with endless possibilities. From no login required at all, to heavily secured login systems with multiple factor authorization.

Comment: If you want the wordpress login as it comes out of the box, you would have to authorize your app users with credentials present in the wordpress database. Meaning: an existing user has to log in with username and password from your app. (You need https for this to be secure.)

Comment: Here is a plugin that does logins via ajax: https://wp-tutorials.tech/optimise-wordpress/wordpress-ajax-login-form/

Comment: You can have a look at their code and see how it is done. In the end, you would need a cookie set for each request.